# get the total likes count and message count using mediaid/post id graph api/Instagram api and get isuser following you or not

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I Just want to trigger graph api for getting total count of likes/comments count of respective media_id.

```
new Request(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), "/" + Post_Id
                    + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.GET,

            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    /* handle the result */
                    Debug.e("posted id  likes responses", response.toString());

                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();

                    Debug.e("posted id  graph responses",
                            graphResponse.toString());

                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

2. Can we get likes/comments count of media_id using instagram rest api. i have searched their doc. i could nt find any endpoint for it.

3.do we have jsonobject for Instagram to tell me that the this user has following you or not ,Similar to **Is_User_Liked** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media endpoint returns the number of likes and comments for a media:

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media

Look for `data.comments.count` and `data.likes.count` in the JSON response.

Comment: Thanks ! One morething i wanted to know.can we know whether user has followed or not  like user_has_liked.. i want get target user has followed or not.

Comment: Yes, using the [Relationship Endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/).

Comment: ya i have seen it.i dont want to call reltionship for everyuser.is there any object similary like user_has_liked for following (need it while searching)